# Why JVM taking three times more memory in production than localhost?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-crash

My webApp in prod (linus, tomcat 7.0.22) takes 390 MB memory where as same takes about 106 MB in local environment. I am continue to investigate heap issues using eclipse MAT but don't understand why same App would consume so drastically different memory in prod ? Any clues will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure certain you are looking at active RAM usage and not the process's cache usage? Linux works with RAM differently than Windows.

Comment: do you have the same configurations between your dev and production servers (Operation System, java runtime, servlet container, ...)? also you might want to configure your jvm to dump the heap on crash, so as to give you proper material for investigation.

Comment: some more details - prod is Linux with tomcat 7.0.22. Local is windows running tomcat under eclipse. Now I am looking at heap dump using MAT , it shows 49 MB used by objects. Still wondering out of 350 MB if java objects is just 49 MB then who is consuming rest ??

Comment: @Amit The Java runtime (and all its libraries, including `libc`) and the code for your application and all its libraries.

Answer (score 2):

1. Roughly, a Java application always uses about as much memory as you allocate to it with -Xmx. In production the heap expands to that limit until the garbage collector kicks in. However, that is quite a simplification the rules when the JVM expands or shrinks the heap space are a litte more complex.
2. The JIT will produce more and larger machine code in production.

So if you just start your application locally and warm it up with a few clicks, there no more object garbage, which keeps the heap expanding. And there is no need to JIT the methods because nobody uses it frequently.

Answer (score 1):

That difference is trivial, and a few hundred megabytes is still reasonably small for a running application. There doesn't seem to be a problem here.